# CASE .. THEN in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

```
item    |   user    |   times   |   data    |   id
--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------
item1   | user1     |   1       | data1     | 1
item2   | user1     |   1       | data2     | 2
item3   | user1     |   1       | data3     | 3
item1   | user2     |   2       | data1     | 4
item2   | user2     |   2       | data2     | 5
```

Above is sample data from my database.
I want to count how many items user1 have in first time that also be proceed in second time.
In this case the result should return 2, because there are 2 items that user1 proceed in 1st time and user2 proceed in 2nd time.
But I'm not able to build the SQL statement after many attempts.

Could anyone help to solve this?

Comment: What do you means when you say `have result` ? Did it means by `having record that has that item`? In this case item1, 2, 3 have record with `times = 1` and `user = 'user1'` but only item1,2 have record with `time <> 1` ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, sorry about my post, i just edited

Comment: I'm surprised at the Approves on the edit. I know this post is confusing, but seriously, changing "many item user1 did in first time" to "many item user1 have in first time"? And the rest is so minor that it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how the question title is related to the question itself. However here is a way to get what you want:

```
select count(*)
from t t1
where "user" = 'user1' and times = 1 and exists (
  select *
  from t t2
  where times = 2 and t1.data = t2.data);
```

EDIT : I just transformed exists into not exists to match your question edit :-)

Comment: Thanks Fabian, i try with CASE...THEN in postgres to get the result then i named the post is CASE...THEN, sorry for that.

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry about the title, I was just surprised when I read the question ;-) (I just edited my answer according to the new question)

Comment: Thanks you again, Fabian, you save my time, i go around with function and CASE...THEN and forget about self join... that is stupid. thanks for your suggestion, i will try to complete it.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, it works like a charm. Thanks you ^____^

Comment: Glad that it helped :-)

Comment: @J.Parker: it this answered your question you should mark the answer  as accepted so that your question is marked as "solved"